# Why do I get 'ReplaceContent' attribute is not declared?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have a SharePoint 2013 dev machine. I've built an app and need to be able to use ReplaceContent="TRUE" on some of the items within my Elements.xml files so that when I publish and install a new version to my production SharePoint these elements get updated.

I cannot run my app in Visual Studio if any of the Elements.xml files have ReplaceContent="TRUE". I get the error The 'ReplaceContent' attribute is not declared. I've already found answers that talk about going to the location C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server  Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\ and making the appropriate edits to the wss.xsd file. These edits have not worked.

Any other idea or things that I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So far, the only quick workaround I've found is to remove that attribute from the Elements.xml files.
This isn't exactly a clean fix (as I'm not exactly sure what this content replacement is about) but it at least allows me to deploy successfully.
Hopefully this'll be of use to some.